# float-css overlaps next to div image

Tags: css, html, css-float, clearfix

My logo and navigation float to the left and right respectively when the screen gets to `40rem`. However it overlaps with the next `div` which contains a background image. I tried setting margins but that just moved both logo/nav and the image lower on the page.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700,900');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 70em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.clearfix::after,
section::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/* typography
    ================= */

.unstyled-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* header
    ================= */

header {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 1em;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.125em;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .8rem;
  padding: .75em;
  color: #DDD;
}


/* home-main
    ================= */

.home-main {
  background-image: url('../manjitcss/img/manjit-main.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 10em 0;
}

@media(min-width:40rem) {
  .logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: .5em;
  }
  nav {
    float: right;
  }
}

@media(min-width:60rem) {
  .logo {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  nav {
    margin-top: .5em;
  }
  nav a {
    font-size: 1.04em;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="../manjitcss/img/logo.jpg" alt="Foo logo" class="logo">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section class="home-main">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you provide working snippet code..?

Comment: i really dont understand can u do a screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `.clearfix` in your css, but you have not *applied* them to `header` *whose* contents you are floating.

Add the class to `header` - see demo below:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700,900');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 70em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.clearfix::after,
section::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/* typography
================= */

.unstyled-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* header
================= */

header {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 1em;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.125em;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .8rem;
  padding: .75em;
  color: #DDD;
}


/* home-main
================= */

.home-main {
  background-image: url('../manjitcss/img/manjit-main.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 10em 0;
}

@media(min-width:40rem) {
  .logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: .5em;
  }
  nav {
    float: right;
  }
}

@media(min-width:60rem) {
  .logo {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  nav {
    margin-top: .5em;
  }
  nav a {
    font-size: 1.04em;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="clearfix">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Foo logo" class="logo" />
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section class="home-main">
  <div class="container">
   container
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks, that solved the problem. I thought clearfix was applied automatically to all header and footer, which is clearly wasn't!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `float` try to use `overflow` property on parent. As float leaves its parent. Or you can use `clearfix` also.

Comment: I used clearfix as well:
    .clearfix::after,
    section::after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        clear :both;
    }

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix i think `display: table` will come.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with float. You may use clearfix or apply float for .home-main as below

```
@media(min-width:40rem) {
      .logo {
        float: left;
        margin-top: .5em;
      }
      nav {
        float: right;
      }
     .home-main{
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
      }
    }
```